# Utilizar hook para despues de crear productos en PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, symfony2, prestashop, prestashop1.7

EStimados estot tratando de utilizar el hook para que una vez creado el producto pueda lamar a una API.
El problema es que no estoy econtrando el hook correspondiente.
la instalacion de mi modulo tengo estos hook:

```
 */
public function install()
{
    return parent::install()
        && $this->runInstallation()
        && $this->registerHook('actionObjectProductUpdateAfter')
        && $this->registerHook('actionObjectProductDeleteAfter')
        && $this->registerHook('actionObjectProductSaveAfter')
        && $this->registerHook('actionProductAdd')
        && $this->registerHook('actionProductSave')
        && $this->registerHook('actionProductDelete')
        && $this->registerHook('actionGetProductPropertiesAfter');

}
```

Para llamar al hook utlizo :

```
public function hookActionObjectProductAddAfter(array $params)
{
     var_dump($params);
     die();

}


public function hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter(array $params)
{
    var_dump($params);
    die();

}


public function hookActionObjectProductDeleteAfter(array $params)
{
    var_dump($params);
    die(); //return 
}
```

EL proble es que este hook hookActionObjectProductAddAfter se ejecuta al apretar el boton nuevo producto y no cuando quiero grabarlo, al nuevo producto.

Alguien cual es el hook que tengo que urilizar para PrestaShop en after de cada evento (guardar,editar,eliminar).

Answer (score 1):

Estoy usando una hook cuando se eliminan las categorías.

El script ha de eliminar un registro cuando se ha elimina una  categoría.

Le he puesto un **condicional** para que este se ejecute en ciertas circunstancias,

¿Quizás tu deberias poner el condicional para dar paso a tu script?

Para evitar que se ejecute al cargar el Hook.

Dejo mi hook ...

```
   /**
    * Clean ssd_ids_categories
    */
    public function hookActionCategoryDelete() {

          if(gettype(Tools::getValue('categoryBox')) != 'array') {
                $currentidcategoria=(int)Tools::getValue('id_category');
                \Db::getInstance()->delete('ssd_ids_categories', 'id_category_local = '.(int)$currentidcategoria, 1);
            } else {
              foreach(Tools::getValue('categoryBox') as $ids) {
                      \Db::getInstance()->delete('ssd_ids_categories', 'id_category_local = '.(int)$ids, 1);
                  }
           }
    }
```

Comment: entiendo y esta muy bien, pero el problema que no encutro el hook para comenzar a manipular los datos. Es decir que cuando hago click en guardar (boton) me aparece un alerta diciedo "configuracion actualizada" pero no puedo lograr manipular los datos que salen al crear el producto..

Comment: `actionProductSave` prueba con este. Fuente: (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/) Según la fuente: `This hook is called while saving products`